# array work at the for loop with try catch? (node.js and javascript) i got error 'ReferenceError: p is not defined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, try-catch

array work at the for loop with try catch (node.js  and javascript) i got error 'ReferenceError: p is not defined'

the code is

```
  for(var i = 0; i<12; i++ ){
  try{
    var incre = i;
    var name = 'pic'+ incre.toString();
    p[i] = req.files[name][0].path;
  } catch (error) {
    p[i] = null;
  }};
```

i got error 'ReferenceError: p is not defined'
node server say 'p' is problem which this array. 
it is process of insert multer path at each array which is p[1] p[2] p[3] .... [p11]

Comment: You never declared `p`. This is what the error tells you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `p`.

```js
let p = []; // Add this line
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  try {
    var incre = i;
    var name = 'pic' + incre.toString();
    p[i] = name;
  } catch (error) {
    p[i] = null;
  }
};

console.log(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the array `p` outside the loop and inside the loop set the values for the array, like this

```js
let p = []

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  try {
    var incre = i;
    var name = 'pic' + incre.toString();
    p[i] = req.files[name][0].path;
  } catch (error) {
    p[i] = null;
  }
};

console.log(p)
```